# Use search script froma previous search emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs23

I'm an emacs newbie . 
I use C-s "text"  to search for a text. 
How do I select from a previous search buffer to research an entry instead of typing it allover again . 
For instance 
C-S "text1" 
C-S "text2" 
Is there a shortcut to remeber text1 so I dont have to type it again while I search for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press <kbd>C-s C-s</kbd> you will search for whatever you searched for the last time.

Using <kbd>M-p</kbd> you can walk up in the search history and also edit the search string. Press <kbd>RET</kbd> to continue searching.

Comment: M-p however does nothing for me . I'm able to get M-x but M-p just shows up as Esc-p or Alt-p . What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You can just use `ESC p` instead of `Alt-p` (`M-p`). E.g., `C-s ESC p`.

Comment: And BTW, since it might be related in use: You can search for any text that you select, including from another application than Emacs, by (a) copying it and then (b) using `M-y` within Isearch. E.g., copy the text `foobar` from some application, then `C-s M-y` yanks `foobar` onto the end of the current search string (which is empty, to start with).